# How to print what year the code was executed in Python

Tags: python, date, python-3.x

So I know how to print a whole date or time or both together but i'm not sure how would you print the year only.
Any suggestions ?

Python 3 BTW

Answer (score 7):

[`datetime.date` objects](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) have a [`year` attribute](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.year):

```
from datetime import date

print(date.today().year)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> print(date.today().year)
2013
```

You can get the [same attribute](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.year) from [`datetime.datetime` objects](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> print(datetime.now().year)
2013
```

You can also get the year from the [`time` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html); the [`time.struct_time` structure](http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time) has a `.tm_year` attribute; the structure is a return value for several functions:

```
>>> import time
>>> print(time.localtime().tm_year)
2013
```

Comment: may want to show him how to do it with datetime and strftime also

Comment: @JoranBeasley: `strftime` is more complex than required for just getting the current year..

Comment: I agree but 90% of the time im doin date stuff thats what I want (in this instance its overkill but it probably wouldnt hurt him to see it)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: for *just* the year, `strftime()` is the wrong method, really.